# php - authenticate with one server for access on another server

Tags: php, authentication, curl, ldap

On my local server I have written a script that takes a username & password and confirms it is valid against my LDAP server.

I have a web site professionally hosted on a remote server. I have a CMS on the remote server and I would like users to use their LDAP credentials to gain access to that CMS.

My plan is to have a login form on the remote server. The form will POST the username/password to itself using https. It will then use CURL to POST the username/password again but this time across the internet to my local server, again using https. My local server will be setup to provide a simple "TRUE" or "FALSE" as a response. If the remote server gets back TRUE, session variables are set to permit access.

Security-wise, is this a safe practise. Should I consider another way?

note: I'm not particularly proficient with cURL but I think I can figure out how to do the above.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking, so I ask: does the CMS you've chosen have a authentication framework that you can configure to access your directory server instead of the method you propose?

Comment: no I will be writing the CMS myself. So are you suggesting that I should open up my LDAP server to the public internet (by opening port 636 I guess?), then I can just use the ldap functions on the remote server?

Comment: I was thinking if you were using a CMS with built in auth it would be simpler to do just that. Configure your LDAP server to accept only SSL connections, or non-secure with an immediate Start TLS, and to reject all operations that were not on a secure connection. If you're rolling your own CMS, build in the auth framework from the beginning. For ideas about auth best practices with LDAP, see http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/authentication-best-practices.html

Answer (score 0):

LDAP - Lightweight active directory protocol which is used to communicate with your active directory server. 
 
LDAP is there only to authenticate & access AD server in most secure way.

**Here is the solution for problem :**

Customize existing login functionality of your CMS in a way like - If user his details check with AD server using LDAP whether user is exist in AD, if yes update his credential to your DB(Also keep flag that user is AD enabled), if user is present is AD & not there in your DB create that one. 
Likewise after some time al your user from AD server will migrate to your DB & you are not required to keep seperate application to for user migration.
Also every time authenticating with AD is best to provide security but its all up to you, because after migration of all user you can remove this functionaity.